# How to re-created a Singleton bean on Spring if the Singleton crashes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have 2 beans with @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_APPLICATION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)

Those 2 beans are singletons. Sometimes they crash depending on the amount of concurrent requests. If they crash, and I verify that they have a null value how can I recreated them and refresh the context? Or would it be dangerous, slow and prone to further errors?

Furthermore, what is the best way to create a Singleton so that it would be more stable? Via a factory?

I have the following declaration of my beans inside the RootContextConfiguration class:

```
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_APPLICATION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public MyFinderModels myFinderModels() {
    MyFinderModels myFinderModels = new MyFinderModels();
    return myFinderModels;
}
```

That is declared on my RootContextConfiguration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@EnableAsync(
    mode = AdviceMode.PROXY, proxyTargetClass = true,
    order = 1
)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mydomain.api.service","com.mydomain.api.repositories"}, excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter({
    Controller.class, ControllerAdvice.class }))
@ImportResource({ "classpath:com/mydomain/config/securityConfiguration.xml" })
public class RootContextConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer,
    SchedulingConfigurer { .....
```

If the Bean MyFinderModels crashes, it will become null. Therefore, what is the best way to go on that case? Re-create that at ApplicationContext level or shall I have a better factory to initialize the bean and take care of it if it crashes so that it can be recovered?

It does not crash every time, but when it does I need to restart my container.

I am using Spring version 4.2.3.RELEASE.

Thank you,

C.

Comment: what does it mean for a bean to crash?

Comment: A spring bean itself can't crash. So if you have any problems, show the code where the problem occurs (i.e. the point, where your bean will be null).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Spring or beans but I'm not sure what you mean by a singleton bean "crashing". Maybe you mean the application container is crashing and thus your entire server with it, which would make you lose any non-persisted object state. If that's what you meant, you should probably save the state of your beans somehow and reload it afterwards, and also look into the problem that's making your server/application server crash.

If you meant something else, then I would say that your singleton bean reference is just being overridden by a null value, and not "crashing". And that's probably a bug.

From what I understand of beans and read about Spring, if you don't specify the scope (as you didn't) it'll be the Singleton scope. That means that the Spring framework will create only one instance of your bean. I guess you shouldn't be instantiating the class yourself, so you shouldn't need the myFinderModels() method for anything. You may be using this method to replace references to the original bean.

So, to answer your question: I don't think you should be worrying about creating and much less re-creating your singletons. Focus on getting your bean configuration right and finding where you may be messing with its references and fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

If your Singleton crashes, the entire Spring startup will fail. In general it leads to application fail to startup.
In case if you Singleton initialization may fail (you are creating MyFinderModels instance, but data provider is not available at the moment), you should postpone initialization of corresponding Singleton property.
For example you can create a timer event which will be executed after some delay and perform one more attempt to initialize the required data, and this event will be executed again and again until the data will be initialized. Of course any consumer of myFinderModels should expect null instead of models, and you should think about possible exceptions in myFinderModels() - either catch them in myFinderModels() or every consumer should catch those exceptions.